# Handling multiples forms in django in single views

Tags: django

[image]

as shown in above screenshot. I want to handle all the form independently. Here I'm using generic base view. I didn't know how to handle this situation. so any suggestion would be appreciated. In my case, all  forms are static. and there are almost 60 forms.

Comment: You're looking for formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/
And I would recommend dynamically creating them.

Comment: @Wolph do they act differently, I mean can i submit one form at a time. if then how to distinguish which data came from which form. Here i did't want to save any data in database

Comment: What do you mean by " I want to handle all the form independently" ? and by "all forms are static" ? Please edit your question to give more context and details, eventually a [mcve] etc.

Comment: You can make them act differently, it all depends on your implementation. If you want to have a single large form it will give you a whole list of results, one for each set of input fields. If you just want a submit per form and have a form tag for each than you can use regular form handling.